# Combo box (select) option line height Issue in chrome browser

Tags: css

I have encountered an issue in select element(Combox box) in the chrome browser, whereas it looks okay in firefox. you can see attached image here.

when i hover in select option the text won't come vertically middle.I haven't posted any code part here because i could not re-generate it on fiddle.

Please go through this link below on chrome browser and See field `Type of Enquery` http://organic.draftserver.com/index.php/contacts [image]

Comment: I guess that's obsolete, right? Can't see that on your page anymore.